# how to search by coupon code in magento 2 admin grid on crores of coupon code

Tags: coupon-codes, magento2.4.5

I am using Magento 2.4.5 and i have crores of coupons in the coupon table. so when i am searching coupon code in the backend coupon grid it is taking lot of time. how we can optiomise this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a specific coupon code in a large number of records can be a time-consuming task, but there are some strategies you can use to optimize the search process in Magento 2.

One approach is to create an index for the coupon code column in the database table used for storing the coupon codes, so that the search can be performed faster. This can be done using a database management tool, such as phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench.

Another approach is to use Magento 2's built-in search functionality, which allows you to search for records based on specific criteria. To do this, follow these steps:

Go to the coupon codes grid in the Magento 2 admin panel.
Click on the "Filters" button and select the "Coupon Code" filter.
In the "Coupon Code" filter, enter the coupon code you want to search for and click on the "Apply Filters" button.
This will filter the coupon codes grid to only show records that match the specified coupon code. If the number of records is still too large, you can further refine the search by adding additional filters based on other criteria, such as the coupon type, usage limit, or expiration date.

By using these strategies, you can quickly and efficiently search for a specific coupon code in a large number of records in Magento 2.